# Stream audio from Xbox One to Linux desktop

Tags: audio, streaming, games

Scenario:

1. I play a game on Xbox
2. I have a laptop which plays music
3. I want to mix them up and have both streams of audio to be played
   through same headphones.

What are my options here?

Comment: One option is getting a hardware mixer, and feeding that into your laptops line in. But this is way offtopic here...

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find a software solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

The [GNOME Alsa Mixer](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/835/alsa-mixer/) is just one solution for you; [this article](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/advanced-audio-control-on-linux/) discusses it and other [Linux Mixer Apps](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Linux%20Mixer%20Apps&t=h_&ia=web).

You will also need an [S/PDIF to analog audio converter w/ optical S/PDIF cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FKW4PZ9) to attach to [port 3 on the back of your Xbox One](https://compass-ssl.xboxlive.com/assets/65/39/6539aa6b-0626-4d95-8e09-c483f8fbe89f.png?n=one-back-m.png) and the appropriate [stereo 3.5mm jack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019D048XC) audio cable from the converter to the input of your laptop.

Why convert digital audio to analog? Because Xbox content has DRM, and analog conversion bypasses that.

Comment: I don't understand how is that relevant. how would I get audio stream from Xbox to my Linux laptop?

Comment: Sorry, got interrupted before I could complete.